# How can I retrieve the real name of a user with smack 4.3.5 on android?

Tags: android, plugins, openfire, smack

I need to retrieve the real name of the user before adding him to my roster but I have not found any way to do this. Some of you could advise me to obtain the real name of the user before adding him to my roster.
[image]

```
   roster.addSubscribeListener((from, subscribeRequest) -> {

         //Here I need to get the real name of the user.
    
        return SubscribeListener.SubscribeAnswer.ApproveAndAlsoRequestIfRequired;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving the real name of a user in smack so that you have to manage the name with Vcard (https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html).
vCards are an existing and widely-used standard for personal user information storage, somewhat like an electronic business card.

**below code for saving the Vcard by using XMPP connection**

```
fun updateVCard(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
    val vCardManager: VCardManager = VCardManager.getInstanceFor(connection)
    val vCard = VCard()

    vCard.firstName = firstName
    vCard.lastName = lastName
    vCard.setField("FN", firstName)

    try {
        vCardManager.saveVCard(vCard)
        Log.e("updateVCard", "updateVCard: update success")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.e("updateVCard", "updateVCard: error " + e.message)
    }
```

}

**now this code for fetching user details that stored in Vcard at the server**

val vCard = getUserDetail(jid);
val username = vCard?.getField("FN") + " " + vCard?.lastName

```
fun getUserDetail(JID: String): VCard? {
    var jid: EntityBareJid? = null
    var vCard: VCard? = null
    try {
        jid = JidCreate.entityBareFrom(JID)
        vCard = VCardManager.getInstanceFor(connection).loadVCard(jid) as VCard
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return vCard
}
```